# How to move a feral kitten from my bathroom to a cage?

Tags: cats, feral

I recently rescued a feral kitten (at least a couple of months) from my neighborhood about 3 days ago. When I captured him, I just let him out in my bathroom (from the cage I caught him in), without first taking him to the vet. :-/ Well, I'm noticing that his right eye is milky, and I'm going to take him to the vet tomorrow. He's curled up behind my toilet. What is the least traumatizing way to get him from behind the toilet to a medium sized dog-like cage?

There's no way he's going to let me just pick him up, and he hasn't eaten since I've trapped him (so luring him with food won't work). Does anyone know how I can get him to run into the cage without fully traumatizing him?

P.S. He was eating the same food outside when he was free, so it's not that he doesn't like the food. I think he's just too scared to eat it. Please help!

Comment: Have you tried picking her up and putting her into the cage? Or luring her out from behind the toilet with a cat toy?

Answer (score 5):

This is late, but may be useful for future reference.

With cats truly afraid of people, you just... walk behind or up to them.

So:

1. Have a small, closed room
2. Remove as many hiding spots as possible (at least those you can't get to).
3. Put box down, maybe cover it with a blanket but leave an opening so that it's a nice dark cave/hiding spot.
4. Just follow them around until the cat goes into the box.
5. Close box.

This only works with cats that are skittish and afraid.

Another method is to throw a large blanket or towel over the cat for your protection and grab it then, but this requires a firm grip and the person in question not hesitating.

Yes, the cat will be stressed, there is no way around that really... but needs must.

Comment: Depending on how quickly you need your cat in the crate just setting it down and leaving might be an option. Its a good hiding place and the cat might choose it itself given enough time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a small live trap, you can use that. Make sure it won't hurt the kitten. I used to have the same problem and just used a piece of ham, but if you notice they are eating something else, use that.

Comment: Welcome to Pets, this answer is a bit short, please consider adding some more information, thanks.